# OneSignal says message is delivered but no push notifications are delivered to the device

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, onesignal

We have an app built in React which uses OneSignal via a PHP API to send push notification. Everything looks to be working according to the OneSignal dashboard however no notifications are being received on the device. However we can manually send a test from OneSignal and it comes through to the device.

We have been through the troubleshooting and FAQs on OneSignal but nothing seems to help.

```php
OneSignalMessage::create()
    ->subject($subject)
    ->body($this->message->content)
    ->setData('to', $this->message->chat->makeUrl($notifiable->club))
    ->setParameter('ios_badgeType', 'Increase')
    ->setParameter('ios_badgeCount', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

One nuance: "Delivered" refers to the notification request being delivered to Apple and Google. It does not confirm that the device itself received it. Please contact our support channel at OneSignal.com for further support.